# How to iterate json object field in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, express

There is a JSON for categories with the following structure

```
[
  {
    "category": "Mobiles",
    "sub": [
      {
        "name": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "name": "Samsung"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Televisions",
    "sub": [
      {
        "name": "Lg"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sony"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

First i load data from backend to a variable called categories (On the backend side im using expressjs and pass data with `res.json(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('categories.json'))`)

I want to iterate through categories sub category with

```
{categories.map(function (category, i) {
    return (
            <>
              <h6 Key={i}>{category.category}</h6> //For example: <h6>Mobiles</h6>
              <>... [logic to iterate the current category's sub categories]  ...</> //For example: <p>Apple</p> <p>Samsung</p>
            </>
    );
 })}
```

I tried to use a second map on `category.sub` like `category.sub.map((s,j)=><p Key={j}>{s.name}</p>)` but unfortunely i can't get it work, and I can't describe my problem to Google in English so it can be an easy answer and i am the big L

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting when you try the second map

Comment: The whole page goes white but i don't get any error

Comment: Check that you have data being returned.  I'll post something that worked for me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, uncomment out the console.log to verify data if screen is white.

```
 return (
    <>
      {categories.map(function (category, i) {
        // console.log(category.category );
        // console.log(category.sub );
        return (
          <>
            <h6 key={i}>{category.category}</h6>
            <>
              {category.sub.map(function (sub, j) {
                // console.log(category.category + '' + sub.name);
                return <p key={j}> {sub.name}</p>;
              })}
            </>
          </>
        );
      })}
   </>
 );
```

Data:

```
let categories = [
  {
    category: 'Mobiles',
    sub: [
      {
        name: 'Apple',
      },
      {
        name: 'Samsung',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    category: 'Televisions',
    sub: [
      {
        name: 'Lg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Sony',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Seems like that return was my problem! I am not familiar with react yet, i am still learning, this helps me a lot, thank you so much!

Comment: The key should be on the fragment.